# Django : Trying to display the object from django admin to a HTML page

Tags: django

I'm trying to display text in a HTML page which i'm saving in django admin interface and whenever i save the data and trying to display the text in html page instead of the text a line space was being printed.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWsls.png) attaching the code screenshots here [views file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdKzS.png), [HTML
page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I10Q.png), [Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmKFx.png), [Django Admin Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw8LI.png)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import todolist
def index(request):
    todo=todolist.objects.order_by('id')

    context={'todo': todo}
    return render(request,'todotemplates/index.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class todolist(models.Model):
    text=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: please copy paste your actual code, instead of attaching screenshots

Comment: Posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html use need to use `i` inside loop not `todo`:

```
{% for i in todo %}
    <li class='whatever'>{{ i.text }}</li>  <!-- use i.text  -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your view code to below:

```
def index(request):
    todohtml = ""
    defectsobj1 = PrdDefect.objects.all()
          for eltdefect1 in defectsobj1:
                todohtml = "<li>"+eltdefect1.text+"</li>"

    return  render(request, "page.html", {"todohtml":todohtml})
```

Also can you check you database if you model is saving entries properly in db

Comment: no issue with database. checked few times and there's no error in saving entries.

Comment: Please can you try the code and see if it prints anything

Comment: No,it isn't printing anything. Even avoided the white spaces.